# Error when plotting y function with range of x values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Get this error when trying to plot a function with respect for a range of x values

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'range'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(273, 1273)
print(list(x))
y = -0.7765 + (0.014350 * x) - (0.000012209 * (x ** 2)) + (3.8289e-09 * (x ** 3))
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: use `np.arange` instead of range

Comment: A side note: `range` returns a generator, which is consumed when you do `print(list(x))`. That means you cannot use it again later in `plt.plot(x,y,'r')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the function `range`, it uses python's `range` function which cannot be used in arithmetic directly as it is an iterator. So you get an error saying multiplication is not supported for: `range` and `float`.

When you use NumPy's `arange`, it has an inbuilt ability to handle such arithmetic. Hence, your code should be using that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(273, 1273) # This
y = -0.7765 + (0.014350 * x) - (0.000012209 * (x ** 2)) + (3.8289e-09 * (x ** 3))
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.show()
```